# Fitting models in R where coefficients are subject to linear restriction(s)?

Tags: r, regression, modeling, restrictions

How should I define a model formula in R, when one (or more) exact linear restrictions binding the coefficients is available. As an example, say that you know that b1 = 2*b0 in a simple linear regression model.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Suppose your model is

$ Y(t) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot X_1(t) + \beta_2 \cdot X_2(t) + \varepsilon(t)$

and you are planning to restrict the coefficients, for instance like:

$ \beta_1 = 2 \beta_2$

inserting the restriction, rewriting the original regression model you will get

$ Y(t) = \beta_0 + 2 \beta_2 \cdot X_1(t) + \beta_2 \cdot X_2(t) + \varepsilon(t) $

$ Y(t) = \beta_0 + \beta_2 (2 \cdot X_1(t) + X_2(t)) + \varepsilon(t)$

introduce a new variable $Z(t) = 2 \cdot X_1(t) + X_2(t)$ and your model with restriction will be

$ Y(t) = \beta_0 + \beta_2 Z(t) + \varepsilon(t)$

In this way you can handle any exact restrictions, because the number of *equal signs* reduces the number of unknown parameters by the same number.

Playing with R formulas you can do directly by I() function

```
lm(formula = Y ~ I(1 + 2*X1) + X2 + X3 - 1, data = <your data>) 
lm(formula = Y ~ I(2*X1 + X2) + X3, data = <your data>)
```

Comment: This is pretty clear, but the question was suggesting a restriction between b0 and b1. Should I also create a new variable Z = 2X + 1 and fit a model without intercept?

Comment: I think usualy **I** is used instead of eval in formulas,  i.e. Y~I(1+2*X1)+X2+X3-1

Comment: @gd047: I have updated with a code pieces, yes it is as you say. @mpiktas: will change this, yes it is shorter ;)

Comment: This is a good answer for the general theoretical approach, but for an easier way to actually implement these hypotheses in R, which also has the advantage of not requiring one to estimate multiple models, see `linearHypothesis()` in the `car` package.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make "soft restrictions" it is very natural to do this with Bayesian priors on contrasts (linear combinations of $\beta$s).  See [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/genreg#help-in-specifying-priors).  This doesn't require re-arranging the original model but instead one specifies side constraints.  To make a constraint almost "hard" one can specify a prior standard deviation of, for example, 0.001.  This is a more general way to think about it, exemplified in the example given at the link in which linearity is enforced over one interval of a predictor.

Answer (score 0):

By using the R [bimets](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bimets/index.html) package you can activate restrictions directly into the model definition, so you can modify (or remove) the imposed linear restriction ( e.g. $\beta_1-2*\beta_0=0$ ) without changing the regression equation or code.

More details about the package at the rstudio blog:
https://rviews.rstudio.com/2021/01/22/sem-time-series-modeling/

An example follows:

```
library(bimets)

#define the restricted model
model.txt <- "MODEL
BEHAVIORAL> Y
EQ> Y = b0 + b1*X1 + b2*X2
COEFF> b0 b1 b2
RESTRICT> b1 - 2*b0 = 0
END"

#create regressors
modelData <- list(
  X1=ts(1:10,start=c(2000,1),frequency=1),
  X2=ts(sin(1:10),start=c(2000,1),frequency=1)
)

#create dependant
modelData <- within(modelData,
                 Y <- X1 + X2 + rnorm(1:10,0,1))

#load model and model data
model <- LOAD_MODEL(modelText = model.txt)
model <- LOAD_MODEL_DATA(model,modelData)

#estimate the model
model <- ESTIMATE(model,TSRANGE=c(2000,1,2009,1))

## ESTIMATE output follows commented out:

## Estimate the Model model.txt:
## the number of behavioral equations to be estimated is 1.
## The total number of coefficients is 3.
## 
## _________________________________________
## 
## BEHAVIORAL EQUATION: Y
## Estimation Technique: OLS
## 
## Y                   =   0.4152918   
##                         T-stat. 35.05144    ***
## 
##                     +   0.8305836   X1
##                         T-stat. 35.05144    ***
## 
##                     +   1.503359    X2
##                         T-stat. 6.7449      ***
## 
## RESTRICTIONS:
## b1-2*b0=0
## 
## RESTRICTIONS F-TEST:
## F-value            : 0.104623       
## F-prob(1,7)        : 0.7557996      
## 
## 
## STATs:
## R-Squared                      : 0.9690315   
## Adjusted R-Squared             : 0.9651604   
## Durbin-Watson Statistic        : 2.466047    
## Sum of squares of residuals    : 1.969718    
## Standard Error of Regression   : 0.4955574   
## Log of the Likelihood Function : -6.065912   
## F-statistic                    : 250.3268    
## F-probability                  : 2.546785e-07
## Akaike's IC                    : 18.13182    
## Schwarz's IC                   : 19.03958    
## Mean of Dependent Variable     : 5.173069    
## Number of Observations         : 10
## Number of Degrees of Freedom   : 8
## Current Sample (year-period)   : 2000-1 / 2009-1
## 
## 
## Signif. codes:   *** 0.001  ** 0.01  * 0.05  
## 
## 
## ...ESTIMATE OK

#test real coefficents restriction
print(model$behavioral$Y$coefficients[2] - 2 * model$behavioral$Y$coefficients[1])
## [1] 0
```

In order to test and to perform a regression with a different restriction you can easily change the `RESTRICT>` line, e.g.:

```
RESTRICT> b1 - 2.34*b2 + 0.99*b0 = -12
```

The package does not use the R [formula](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/formula) function.