# Estimating regression where one explanatory variable is a sum of two other variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares

Say I want to estimate the following with OLS:

$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i,1} + \beta_2 x_{i, 2} + \beta_3 x_{i,1} \times x_{i, 2} +\varepsilon_i \cdots (1)$$ for $i=1, 2, \cdots, n$

Now assume that $x_{i,1} = z_{i, 1} + z_{i, 2}$, that is, the independent variable $x_{i, 1}$ can be decomposed into the sum of two other variables $z_{i,1}$ and $z_{i, 2}$ (these two variables are different from $x_{i,2}$). If I substitute this into the above:

$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 (z_{i, 1} + z_{i, 2}) + \beta_2 x_{i, 2} + \beta_3 (z_{i, 1} + z_{i, 2})  \times x_{i, 2} + \varepsilon_i$$
$$= \beta_0 + \beta_1 z_{i, 1} + \beta_1 z_{i, 2} + \beta_2 x_{i, 2}+ \beta_3 z_{i, 1} \times x_{i, 2} + \beta_3 z_{i, 2} \times x_{i, 2} + \varepsilon_i \cdots (2)$$

I want to estimate $(2)$ with OLS, which seems very straightforward, however algebraically from (2), it seems that the coefficients for $z_{i, 1}$ and $z_{i, 2}$ are constrained to be the same? Similarly, those on $z_{i, 1} \times x_{i, 2}$ and $z_{i, 2} \times x_{i, 2}$ are also constrained to be the same. But, obviously estimating $(2)$ with OLS gives different coefficients. Why is this?

Comment: When you estimate the regression in (2) ... how are you keeping the two $\beta_3$ estimates the same? (If you're not, then it's not the same model that you wrote in (2) ...)

Comment: Sorry, I think my question wasn’t very clear. I’m actually seeking something simpler, assuming the $x_{i, 1}$ can be decomposed into the sum, I want to see the effects of $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ on $y$, so can I just simply run OLS by substituting in the decomposition? I am asking because in the algebraic substitution, it appears that some coefficients are the same, so is this something I need to ‘impose’ when I estimate the decomposition using OLS? Or do I even need to follow model (2) to estimate each $z$’s effect on $y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to impose the same coefficients, run (1). If you regress on the separate variables in (2), you are not imposing a restriction and will get different coefficients, as Glen_b explains. My illustration omits $x_{i,2}$ as it does not seem relevant to the problem.

```
n <- 100
z1 <- rnorm(n)
z2 <- rnorm(n)
x <- z1 + z2
> lm(y~x)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
    0.06984      0.08051  


> lm(y~z1+z2)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ z1 + z2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           z1           z2  
   0.063057    -0.001088     0.160663
```

Comment: Thanks! So if I want to estimate the effect of $z_1$ and $z_2$ (and their interactions with $x_2$) on $y$, it is okay econometrically to regress $y$ on $z_1$, $z_2$, $x_2$, and interactions of $z_1$ and $z_2$ with $x_2$? But theoretically the derivation of $(2)$ shows that the effect of $z_1$ on $y$ should be the same as the effect of $z_2$ on $y$ because both coefficients are $\beta_1$? Or am I misunderstanding something really basic?

Comment: What you are, I think, misunderstanding is that the regression `lm(formula = y ~ z1 + z2)` does *not* impose the restriction from (1) (or rewriting (1) as (2)). Maybe this is helpful? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6214/fitting-models-in-r-where-coefficients-are-subject-to-linear-restrictions